# Possible to query to see if a subscriber has completed a Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder, sql

Is it possible to use SQL to find out if a Subscriber has completed a Journey? If not via SQL, does anyone know of another way? I looked at the Journey Data Views but they don't seem like they're meant for this purpose. I know that when a Journey is created it creates a Data Extension, but it appears that subscribers are held forever in that Data Extension (or at least until a new journey version is activated).

I know that I can create a field in Sales Cloud and update that from my journey, to indicate that they have completed the journey, but I'm looking for a wholly SFMC contained method if possible.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you got updateContact Activity set to the end of the journey steps? Also, you can check on the history within journey builder if it has a goal criteria setup

Comment: @BradSapkota thanks for the suggestion. Can I check the history with SQL? I need this to be an automated method. Also, I seem to remember something about them sunsetting the "Update Contact" activity soon.